# How to determine trend of time-series of values in R

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I am looking for help writing a function that can identify a trend ("positive/negative/mixed", see definition below) in a value for a given customer in a dataset.

I have the following transactional data; all customers have between 3-13 transactions each.

```
customer_ID transaction_num sales
Josh         1              $35
Josh         2              $50
Josh         3              $65
Ray          1              $65
Ray          2              $52
Ray          3              $49
Ray          4              $15
Eric         1              $10 
Eric         2              $13
Eric         3              $9
```

I would like to write a function in R that populates a new dataframe as follows

```
Customer_ID     Sales_Slope  
Josh              Positive
Ray               Negative
Eric               Mixed
```

where:

Josh's slope is **positive** because all of his transaction sales costs continue to increase with each additional shopping point

Ray's slope is **negative** because all of his transactions sales costs continue to decrease with each additional shopping point

Eric's slope is **mixed** because all of his transaction sales costs fluctate... with no clear trend...

I have tried quite extensively to do this myself but am stuck.. here is some pseudo-code I have been able to put together

```
counter = max(transaction_num)
while counter >= 0 
 if sales at max transaction_num are greater than sales at max transaction_num - 1) 
   then counter = counter - 1 ; else "not positive slope trend"
```

Comment: You're not looking for 'trend' as in the slope of a 'proper' time-series trend analysis (e.g. ARIMA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would start with something like this.  `data.table` is usually pretty efficient with bigger datasets.

```
#Make fake data
require("data.table")
data <- data.table(customer_ID=c(rep("Josh",3),rep("Ray",4),rep("Eric",3)),
                   sales=c(35,50,65,65,52,49,15,10,13,9))
data[,transaction_num:=seq(1,.N),by=c("customer_ID")]
```

Now for the actual code.

```
data <- data.table(data)

#Calculate difference in rolling two time periods
rolled.up <- data[,list(N.Minus.1=.N-1,Change=list(
  sales[transaction_num+1]-sales[transaction_num])),
  by=c("customer_ID")]

#Sum up positive and negative values
rolled.up[,Pos.Values:=as.numeric(lapply(Change,FUN=function(x) {sum(1*(x>0),na.rm=T)}))]
rolled.up[,Neg.Values:=(N.Minus.1-Pos.Values)]

#Make Sales Slope variable
rolled.up[,Sales_Slope:=ifelse(Pos.Values>0 & Neg.Values==0,"Positive",
      ifelse(Pos.Values==0 & Neg.Values>0,"Negative","Mixed"))]

#Make final table
final.table <- rolled.up[,list(customer_ID,Sales_Slope)]
final.table

#      customer_ID Sales_Slope
# 1:        Josh    Positive
# 2:         Ray    Negative
# 3:        Eric       Mixed

#You can always merge this result back onto your main dataset if you want
data <- merge(x=data,y=final.table,by=c("customer_ID"),all.x=T)
```

Comment: my mistake.  I just changed it.  It should be ``by=c("customer_ID")``.  So what is the final data.table that you would like to see?  You can always merge this back on to the main data.table.  ``merge(x=data,y=final.table,by=c("customerID"),all.x=T)``.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to use `diff`. It just subtracts the current value from the next, so if all of `diff(x)` is above zero, it is increasing, and vice-versa. First, read the data:

```
# Read in some data.
data<-read.table(textConnection('customer_ID transaction_num sales
Josh         1              $35
Josh         2              $50
Josh         3              $65
Ray          1              $65
Ray          2              $52
Ray          3              $49
Ray          4              $15
Eric         1              $10 
Eric         2              $13
Eric         3              $9'),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data$sales<-as.numeric(sub('\\$','',data$sales))
```

Now the code:

```
# Diff subtracts next value from current in a diff.
# so diff(c(1,2,3,4)) is c(1,1,1)
direction<-function(x){
  if(all(diff(x)>0)) return('Increasing')
  if(all(diff(x)<0)) return('Decreasing')
  return('Mixed')
}

# If you want a vector.
c(by(data$sales,data$customer_ID,direction))
#   Eric         Josh          Ray 
# "Mixed" "Increasing" "Decreasing"

# If you want to a little data frame.
aggregate(sales~customer_ID,data,direction)
#   customer_ID      sales
# 1        Eric      Mixed
# 2        Josh Increasing
# 3         Ray Decreasing
```

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you. I am trying to look inside this "diff" function in R, and I can't get record of it...googling it does not provide much answers, so I prefer the traditional way, but this doesn't work

methods(diff) 
getAnywhere('diff')

Any thoughts on how I can view exactly what it is doing?

Comment: diff() is a base-R function.  Just type '?diff' at the command line to look at the description and examples at the end.

Comment: How do I see the source code of the function? To see how it is written?

Comment: @blast00 Just type `diff.default` to see the source. But, it is probably easier to understand in English. `diff` takes the second value, and the subtracts the first value, then take the third value, and subtracts the second, and repeats the process all the way to the end.