# Determine Sales trend with multiple variables like Customer ID/Item etc

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, summary, trend

I got stuck while working on trends. My problem is similar to this below thread but I have one extra variable called 'item'.

[How to determine trend of time-series of values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600385/how-to-determine-trend-of-a-series-of-values-in-r)

My end result would be like below sample. Please help

```
Customer_ID Item    Sales_Slope  
Josh        milk      Positive
Josh         eggs      Negative
Eric         milk      Mixed
Eric         eggs      postive
```

My Data:

```
require("data.table")
dat <- data.table(
            customer_ID=c(rep("Josh",6),rep("Ray",7),rep("Eric",7)),
            item=c(rep("milk",3),rep("eggs",3),rep("milk",4),rep("eggs",3),rep("milk",3),rep("eggs",4)),
            sales=c(35,50,65,65,52,49,15,10,13,9,35,50,65,65,52,49,15,10,13,9))

dat[,transaction_num:=seq(1,.N), by=c("customer_ID")]
```

Comment: Other than the data.table and asking about multiple 'by' keys, this bears a strong resemblance/is a possible duplicate of [how to determine trend of a series of values in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600385/how-to-determine-trend-of-a-series-of-values-in-r). Are these some standard  example or homework?

Comment: The part about how to [How to group data.table by multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478943/r-data-table-group-by-multiple-columns) is to use `by=list("customer_ID","item")`, not `by=c(...)`

Comment: @smci - Your solution is not working.   Error: Error in `[.data.table`(data, , list(N.Minus.1 = .N - 1, Change = list(sales[transaction_num +  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (20).

Comment: Yes it is. The compound group-by goes in the expression that calculates Sales_Slope - not in your line that assigns transaction_num! See my answer. Also, you're supposed to read the link to the near-duplicate.

Comment: @smci - Thank you. I am new to R. Your solution is working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the data.table approach which I outlined was:

```
require(data.table)

trend <- function(x) {
   ifelse(all(diff(x)>0), 'Positive',
   ifelse(all(diff(x)<0), 'Negative', 'Mixed'))
}

dat[, trend(sales), by=c("customer_ID","item")]
   customer_ID item       V1
1:        Josh milk Positive
2:        Josh eggs Negative
3:         Ray milk    Mixed
4:         Ray eggs Positive
5:        Eric milk Negative
6:        Eric eggs    Mixed

# or if you want to assign the result...
dat[, Sales_Slope:=trend(sales), by=c("customer_ID","item")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @smci that all that changed from that link is that "by" variable has increased. I hope this solution makes it clear

```
> library(plyr)
> abc <- function(x){
   if(all(diff(x$sales)>0)) return('Positive')
   if(all(diff(x$sales)<0)) return('Negative')
   return('Mixed')
  }

 y= ddply(dat, .(customer_ID, item), abc)
 y
  customer_ID item       V1
1        Eric eggs    Mixed
2        Eric milk Negative
3        Josh eggs Negative
4        Josh milk Positive
5         Ray eggs Positive
6         Ray milk    Mixed
```

Comment: Thank you both. The solution did work like charm. :-) Very much appreciated and thank for your contribution to community. We love R

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: Nested `ifelse(...)` is a nicer cleaner idiom, it also allows you to write it as an expression without cluttering it with `return` statements. See my answer.